# Lambda on pandas behavior unable to understand

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe :

```
df2.head(5)
Out[78]: 
    User        Date                   movie
0  User1  2019-07-02  [Bridge to Terabithia]
1  User1  2019-07-04              [Defiance]
2  User1  2019-07-05                 [Click]
3  User1  2019-07-07              [Big Stan]
4  User1  2019-07-14    [Death at a Funeral]
```

Where the elements of movie column are list data type, now that i am trying to run a lambda function as follows:

```
df2['movie'] = df2['movie'].apply(lambda x : x[0])

df2.head(5)
Out[79]: 
    User        Date               movie
0  User1  2019-07-02 Bridge to Terabithia
1  User1  2019-07-04                 NaN
2  User1  2019-07-05                 NaN
3  User1  2019-07-07                 NaN
4  User1  2019-07-14                 NaN
```

While the desired output is

```
    User        Date               movie
0  User1  2019-07-02              Bridge to Terabithia
1  User1  2019-07-04              Defiance
2  User1  2019-07-05              Click
3  User1  2019-07-07              Big Stan
4  User1  2019-07-14              Death at a Funeral
```

Unable to understand why its giving me output like that ?

Comment: try `df2.movie.str[0]` , also your code runs fine for me, cannot reproduce the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please next time include a fully reproducible example (including the code to create the dataframe), that will save time to all reviewers.

Your code runs fine for me:

```
import pandas as pd

# data
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'User': ['User1'] * 5,
                    'Date': ['2019-07-02',
                             '2019-07-04',
                             '2019-07-05',
                             '2019-07-07',
                             '2019-07-14'],
                    'movie': [
                        ['Bridge to Terabithia'],
                        ['Defiance'],
                        ['Click'],
                        ['Big Stan'],
                        ['Death at a Funeral']
                    ]})

print(df2.head(5))
print()

df2['movie'] = df2['movie'].apply(lambda x : x[0])
print(df2.head(5))
```

Which yields:

```
         Date   User                   movie
0  2019-07-02  User1  [Bridge to Terabithia]
1  2019-07-04  User1              [Defiance]
2  2019-07-05  User1                 [Click]
3  2019-07-07  User1              [Big Stan]
4  2019-07-14  User1    [Death at a Funeral]

         Date   User                 movie
0  2019-07-02  User1  Bridge to Terabithia
1  2019-07-04  User1              Defiance
2  2019-07-05  User1                 Click
3  2019-07-07  User1              Big Stan
4  2019-07-14  User1    Death at a Funeral
```

Now when I personally want to debug `.apply` with lambda functions, what I usually do is to use a normal function first, where I can put breakpoints and inspect what happens. Then when it is correct I replace it with the lambda function. So that's what I would have done in your case:

```
def extract_first(x):
    # here you can put breakpoints, print stuff, etc.
    return x[0]

df2['movie'] = df2['movie'].apply(extract_first)
```

Comment: Thanks Stan for driving my attention  to creation of dataframe, thats where i had faultered, using df2.columns = [['User', 'Date', 'movie']] for naming the columns.